# Ethernet to USB adapter (with power supply)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, router, ethernet

My internet setup is as follows:

Internet > wireless > 4G router > wireless > Main Router > PC (wired) and other devices (wireless)

As you can see the Main Router (which I connect all of my devices to, because it's faster in terms of internal network speeds and has a longer WI-FI range) connects to the 4G router (which is the access point to the Internet) wirelessly.

I want both routers to be wired. However, the 4G router has only a single Micro USB port which also acts as a power supply and the Main Router has no USB ports.

So what sort of (Micro) USB to Ethernet adapter should I buy (suggestions from experience welcome)?

Is it possible to transfer power from the Main Router through its Ethernet port?

If I use an adapter with a separate power supply, will it supply the 4G router through the Micro USB port?

Models:
Main Router: Tenda W308R
4G Router: Is an Infomark Biscuit Mini provided and customized by my ISP.

Answer (score 1):

A Micro USB to Ethernet port won't work if the 4G router doesn't have the capability, which I would assume it doesn't.

Why don't you buy a router that replaces all of these? Purchase a decent 4G router, I'm in NZ and 4G doesn't exist here yet, but surely there is an alternative. ISPs generally purchase cheap routers and give them to customers as it saves them a lot of money. Whether or not this is the case here I don't know.

You could also throw another repeater in but place it beside the 4G router. If you don't know what you are doing it could make your network quite messy. Also, couldn't you just wire a modem/router/switch up to the 4G router, effectively giving it more ports? Just let your other router handle all of the DHCP IP allocations.

Comment: Could you clarify which capability are you talking about? The 4G router does support USB Tethering if that's what you mean.